# Inno script not detecting that vcredist_x64.exe is not installed

Tags: inno-setup, vcredist

I have the following code in my Inno Setup script:

```
[Files]

Source: "C:\Users\Myname\Documents\Visual Studio 
2010\Redistributional\vcredist_x86.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: 
deleteafterinstall;
Source: "C:\Users\Myname\Documents\Visual Studio 
2010\Redistributional\vcredist_x64.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: 
deleteafterinstall;   

[Run]

Filename: "{tmp}\vcredist_x86.exe"; Parameters: "/install /passive"; Check: 
not IsWin64 and not VCinstalled32
Filename: "{tmp}\vcredist_x64.exe"; Parameters: "/install /passive"; Check: 
IsWin64 and not VCinstalled64
Filename: "{app}\Myprogram.exe"; Description {cm:LaunchProgram,Myprogram}";

[Code]

function VCinstalled32: Boolean;
var
installed: Cardinal;
key: String;
begin
 Result := False;
 key := 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\Runtimes\x86';
 if DirExists 
 ('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\Runtimes\x86') 
 then begin  
   if RegQueryDWordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key, 'Installed', installed) 
   then begin  
     if installed = 1 then begin
      Result := True;
     end;
   end;
 end;
end;

function VCinstalled64: Boolean;
var
installed: Cardinal;
key: String;
begin
  Result := False;
  key := 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\Runtimes\x64';
  if DirExists 
 ('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\Runtimes\x64') 
    then begin 
      if RegQueryDWordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key, 'Installed', installed) 
        then begin  
          if installed = 1 then begin
            Result := True;
          end;
      end;
   end;
 end;
```

I have tried to run this on a 64 bits Windows 10 machine in which the directory `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\Runtimes\x64` does not exist, but I get an error message saying that MSVCR100 is not found.

Thanks in advance.

## Update

Thank you very much for you answer, but still I get the same error message. Maybe I have overlooked something.

## Update

I am not very acquainted with Inno script and don't know anything about how to log the result. I have tried to google the latter, but it seems to be very complicated, so I'll try to wait with this to later, if I can't find the answer in any other way.

## Update

Here is some of the output from the Log file:

```
2018-03-05 14:01:03.567   -- File entry --
2018-03-05 14:01:03.568   Dest filename: C:\Users\Bruker\AppData\Local\Temp\is-SP07M.tmp\vcredist_x86.exe
2018-03-05 14:01:03.568   Time stamp of our file: 2018-02-18 14:27:32.000
2018-03-05 14:01:03.568   Installing the file.
2018-03-05 14:01:04.016   Successfully installed the file.
2018-03-05 14:01:04.017   -- File entry --
2018-03-05 14:01:04.018   Dest filename: C:\Users\Bruker\AppData\Local\Temp\is-SP07M.tmp\vcredist_x64.exe
2018-03-05 14:01:04.018   Time stamp of our file: 2018-02-18 16:00:00.000
2018-03-05 14:01:04.018   Installing the file.
2018-03-05 14:01:04.937   Successfully installed the file.
2018-03-05 14:01:08.883   -- Run entry --
2018-03-05 14:01:08.883   Run as: Current user
2018-03-05 14:01:08.883   Type: Exec
2018-03-05 14:01:08.883   Filename: C:\Users\Bruker\AppData\Local\Temp\is-SP07M.tmp\vcredist_x64.exe
2018-03-05 14:01:08.883   Parameters: /install /passive
2018-03-05 14:01:21.800   Process exit code: 0
2018-03-05 14:01:21.800   -- Run entry --
2018-03-05 14:01:21.800   Run as: Current user
2018-03-05 14:01:21.800   Type: Exec
2018-03-05 14:01:21.800   Filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Myfile\myfile.exe
2018-03-05 14:01:28.020   Process exit code: 3221225781
2018-03-05 14:01:28.023   Need to restart Windows? No
2018-03-05 14:01:30.504   Deinitializing Setup.
2018-03-05 14:01:30.593   Log closed.
```

As I have understood,  `Process exit code: 0` means that the file has executed successfully, so I still don't understand what could be wrong.

Comment: Have you run the installer from the command line and used the log parameter to log the results to a text file. Then you can identify the issue in the script.

Comment: See updated answer. Logging has nothing to do with scripting. Bring up a command prompt. Change to directory of executable. Type your setup file name with a space and /log=..  Also when editing your question don’t replace original code. Add it at the bottom.

Comment: See updated answer with more details about logging.

Comment: The log is useful. In the log it executes `Filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Myfile\myfile.exe`. What is that? It has a weird exit code. Is that valid?

Comment: Also, which redistributables are you trying to install?

Comment: I think your problem is you are doing the “not Win64” check so you never install the 32 bit redist. Your app is 32 bit. Remove that check

Answer (score 2):

I just read up on **MSVCR100.DLL**:

> **MSVCR100.dll** = Visual Studio 2010 Runtime
>
> **MSVCR110.dll** = Visual Studio 2012 Runtime
>
> **MSVCR120.dll** = Visual Studio 2013 Runtime

So are you actually installing the correct redistributables?

---

With respects to your script, why are you using `DirExists`? That is designed to verify if a [directory](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_direxists) exists. You are working with the [registry](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_regkeyexists.htm) so you should be using `RegKeyExists`. The help provides an example:

```
begin
  if RegKeyExists(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\Jordan Russell\Inno Setup') then
  begin
    // The key exists
  end;
end;
```

I have not tested this but you would want something like:

```
function VCinstalled64: Boolean;
var
installed: Cardinal;
key: String;
begin
  Result := False;
  key := 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\Runtimes\x64';
  if RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key) then
  begin 
      if RegQueryDWordValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key, 'Installed', installed) 
        then begin  
          if installed = 1 then begin
            Result := True;
          end;
      end;
   end;
 end;
```

The other method `VCinstalled32` would need similar changes.

## Logging

The **help system** supplied with Inno Setup (also online) explains about [logging](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setupcmdline.htm#LOG2):

> **/LOG**
> Causes Setup to create a log file in the user's TEMP directory detailing file installation and [Run] actions taken during the installation process. This can be a helpful debugging aid. For example, if you suspect a file isn't being replaced when you believe it should be (or vice versa), the log file will tell you if the file was really skipped, and why.
>
> The log file is created with a unique name based on the current date. (It will not overwrite or append to existing files.)
>
> The information contained in the log file is technical in nature and therefore not intended to be understandable by end users. Nor is it designed to be machine-parsable; the format of the file is subject to change without notice.
>
> **/LOG="filename"**
> Same as /LOG, except it allows you to specify a fixed path/filename to use for the log file. If a file with the specified name already exists it will be overwritten. If the file cannot be created, Setup will abort with an error message.

---

- So, from the Windows Start Menu type in the box `cmd` and click on **Command Prompt**:

[image: Command Prompt Menu]

- Next, navigate to the folder where the installer is and run it with the `/log` parameter:

[image: Command Prompt]

Edit your question and add the output from the log to it. Also consider replacing your snippet of script with your complete script (the original script that used `DirExists`.

---

I have done a bit more research and found this interesting [question](https://superuser.com/questions/695704/do-i-need-both-x64-and-x86-versions-of-the-c-redist). If you look at your log output it only installs the 64 bit edition:

```
2018-03-05 14:01:08.883   -- Run entry --
2018-03-05 14:01:08.883   Run as: Current user
2018-03-05 14:01:08.883   Type: Exec
2018-03-05 14:01:08.883   Filename: C:\Users\Bruker\AppData\Local\Temp\is-SP07M.tmp\vcredist_x64.exe
2018-03-05 14:01:08.883   Parameters: /install /passive
2018-03-05 14:01:21.800   Process exit code: 0
```

Change this line from:

```
Filename: "{tmp}\vcredist_x86.exe"; Parameters: "/install /passive"; Check: not IsWin64 and not VCinstalled32
```

to:

```
Filename: "{tmp}\vcredist_x86.exe"; Parameters: "/install /passive"; Check: not VCinstalled32
```

Your executable appears to be 32 bit, and based on that question I referred to it states:

> No, you need the x86 version to run 32-bit VC++ programs, and you need the x64 version to run 64-bit VC++ programs.

Comment: Again, thank you very much for your help. It's very much appreciated. I have added some of the data from the log file above.

Comment: @Vatar You are welcome. Please see my comment on your question (also, please consider deleting your mistaken answer). Or flagging your own answer for removal.

Comment: I have compiled the program in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express. So I went into the Microsoft download center and downloaded Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64), which I guess is the same that I did the first time. It seems however that the latter file is another version than the first, because the size is different, the first is 9,8 mb while the latter is 5,5 mb, and also the time stamp of the last one is earlier than the first, which I find strange. Anyway, I tried to use this last file, but still I got the same error message.

Comment: I suggest you try to manually install the redist from the command line and afterwards verify the existence of the DLL file on your C drive. Also, and I don’t know if it matters, but the bitness might be important. Your log installed a 64 bit redist. But your app failed. Is your app 64 or 32 bit?

Comment: Also, it might be advantageous to see the whole script.

Comment: So what you are saying is that it is dependent on the program and not the machine. Then I have totally misunderstood. I thought it was the opposite. So that means that I'll use the same vcredist file whether I install the program on a 32 or 64 bits machine?

Comment: I have also read the following: 64-bit mode is selected if the user is running a 64-bit version of Windows and the system's processor architecture is included in the value of the ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode [Setup] section directive. Otherwise, 32-bit mode is used. I am confused what is actually meant by this.

Comment: Ok. I just wanted to be sure that I had understood it correctly, but I guess it's actually quite clear.

Comment: @Vatar `ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode ` is something different and is not your issue. Remove the x64 redistributable from your installer and simply install the x86 one. Since you have a x86 executable.

Comment: @Vatar Great. If you are able to "accept" my answer by ticking it I would be grateful. :)

Comment: Great that it worked. But when I restarted the program, one of the program's functions didn't work, and I get the message that the program has stopped working. Maybe most likely that one of the files for the program is missing in the setup. I tried to click for you, but got the message that since I have less than  15 reputation it will not show on the screen, but that it will be registered. Best regards

Comment: @Vatar OK ... :) You best do some research on whatever other issues you are encountering and if you can't resolve them raise separate questions. One at a time. StackOverflow has a trigger that can blacklist a user if they ask too many questions too quickly. And you will be more likely to get answers if you limit a question to a specific issue and show your research etc.

Comment: I understand. I will do some research and ask a new question if I don't find the answer after some time.